# Randomly distributing in dynamic array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have a dynamic array and an Integer which has a value 3 times array length that is

`Integer = array.length*3`

For example if the array has 4 cells then the integers value is 12 and the distribution can be [8][1][2][1], [5][3][0][4],  [0][12][0][0].

How can I distribute the Integer value between each cells of the array?

Comment: You need to read [ask]

Comment: Do you mean to say that the sum of the cells must equal the integer?  'Cause you never said that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're a student, and this smells like homework, I'll show you a heavily annotated version I implemented it in another language (Ruby) and let you translate it into Java for yourself.

```
# Method to populate an array with values that sum to 3 * the array length
def populate(array)
  total = 3 * array.length    # determine the value to sum to
  # the following allocates a temporary array with one more element
  # than the input array, and populates it with random integers
  # between zero and total, inclusive
  tmp = Array.new(array.length + 1) { rand(total + 1) }
  # replace the first entry with zero, the last with total.
  # in reality, any two entries could be used, but values of
  # zero and total are critical to the algorithm
  tmp[0] = 0
  tmp[-1] = total
  # sort the temp array into ascending order
  tmp.sort!
  # since the smallest entry in tmp is zero, and the largest is total,
  # and the array is in ascending order, successive differences between
  # tmp entries will sum to total
  array.each_index { |i| array[i] = tmp[i + 1] - tmp[i] }
  # return the resulting array
  return array
end
```

When run, this produces results such as

```
[0, 0, 4, 8]
[3, 4, 0, 5]
[2, 1, 6, 3]
```

etc.

The underlying algorithm—generate `n+1` values comprised of 0, `total`, and `n-1` random values in the range [0, `total`], sort, and find the `n` successive differences—is straightforward to implement in any language.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random r = new Random();
int max = array.length * 3;
for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    array[r.nextInt(array.length)] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Yep this is definitely not perfect, but it also certainly won't work.

Comment: I don't have to test it, to see that the distribution is obviously going to be completely skewed towards the first few entries. The math of how this is skewed is more interesting, but if you just want to see that it is broken try it on an array with higher dimensions.

Comment: Well in that case, I'd just go with `arr[0] = max`. As the old saying goes, if it doesn't have to be correct I can make it arbitrarily fast. And no, you have the same bias for anything over 2 array entries - humans are just not particularly great at noticing such things, any statistical test will show the anomoly even for n=4.

Comment: Yep that should be accurate,.